# Hashing Similarity

Tags: hash

Normally, the goal of hashing is to turn a continuous function into a discrete one: a small change in the input should cause a large change in the output. However, is there any hashing algorithm that will, (very) roughly speaking, return similar but (still different) hashes for similar inputs?

(An example of the use of this would be to check whether two files are "similar" by checking their hashes for similarity. Of course, some failure is always acceptable.)

Comment: How do you define "similar" ?

Comment: Two streams of approximately the same length and approximately the same data in the same order would be considered similar. (Note that I don't need to say "Are these two similar?" as a boolean, but rather as some kind of a number-rating-system. For example, [1, 2, 3, 4] might be more similar to [1, 2, 3] than to [4, 3, 2, 1]...)

Comment: The whole point of a hash function is to make sure that a change in any single bit of the input should have a chance of changing *every* bit of the output.

Comment: Maybe "hashing" is a misnomer then... I can't think of any other name for it. :\

Comment: Well you got a good answer!  I recall once looking into the subject of hash functions that maintain ordering relationships - a challenge!

Comment: This is the exact opposite of what hashing does.  You want some kind of anti-hash

Comment: @Chris: Yeah, I guess I do... I'm a rebel. :)

Comment: @Mehrdad, have you been able to find an implementation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at [Locality Sensitive Hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_sensitive_hashing) (LSH).  That is a probabilistic way of quickly finding a bunch of points near a given one, for example.

Comment: +1 seems to be exactly what I was looking for... I didn't know the terms to search for; thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Given a distance function that  tells you how similar or different are your objects, you can also employ distance permutations:
http://www.computer.org/portal/web/csdl/doi/10.1109/TPAMI.2007.70815
or sketches:
http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1638180

For an implementation of the latter approach:
http://obsearch.net

Answer (score -2):

You really don't want to see similar hashes. Hashing is to insure Integrity, therefore the slightest change in your file/app/program will produce an entirely different hash.  If two different strings show the same hash, this is called a collision, and the hashing algorithm is now compromised.  MD5 has some collisions but is still used today.

Comment: Hashing is used for things besides integrity checking.

Comment: what above commenter said, an example of this is [perceptual hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptual_hashing), where the goal is for *similar-looking* images to yield *similar-looking* hashes and you can quantitatively measure this 'similarity' by looking at the hamming-distances between two hashes